# Class inherited from QPushbutton shows no text

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a first project using qt (a simple calculator).
I created a class who inherits from QPushButton, code compiles without warning, but the button created appears empty. 
I don't understand why it's not showing 42...

Here's the code :

main.cpp :

```
#include "bouton_chiffre.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    bouton_chiffre w(42, 0);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

bouton_chiffre.h :

```
#ifndef BOUTON_CHIFFRE_H
#define BOUTON_CHIFFRE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class bouton_chiffre : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    bouton_chiffre(int, QWidget*);

private:
    int valeur_du_bouton;
    QPushButton *le_bouton;
};

#endif // BOUTON_CHIFFRE_H
```

bouton_chiffre.cpp :

```
#include "bouton_chiffre.h"

bouton_chiffre::bouton_chiffre(int valeur_init, QWidget *parent)
{
    valeur_du_bouton = valeur_init;
    le_bouton = new QPushButton(QString::number(valeur_init), parent);
}
```

Comment: Why does bouton_chiffre also contain a button le_bouton?

Comment: Probabily because I'm a noob who should read his code better :D 

It works well now, thanks

Comment: @ftynse answer looks good though, we were all noobs at some point  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting up the text for the parent button class, but creating a new instance of this class in `le_bouton`.

Do something like this in constructor:

```
bouton_chiffre::bouton_chiffre(int valeur, QWidget *parent)
  : QPushButton(QString::number(valeur), parent)
{ 
  /*...*/
}
```

You should read more about how inheritance work.  In the derived class, you have access to all protected and public members of the base class, so `setText(QString::number(valuer));` would also work.  In general case, however, you may call the base class constructor from the initialization list (after colon) of the derived class and pass the required arguments.

Creating a *member* of the derived class that has the type of the base class has *nothing* to do with inheritance.  It's just a different object.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was both inheriting from and creating a QPushButton, which of course does not works well... I modified boutonchiffre.cpp as follows, it works as I expected now :

```
#include "bouton_chiffre.h"

bouton_chiffre::bouton_chiffre(int valeur_init, QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    valeur_du_bouton = valeur_init;
    setText(QString::number(valeur_init));
}
```

Using the QPushButton constructor directly instead of setText is maybe more elegant though, I'll probabily do that.

Thank you all for your answers !